# Console Logging - Selenium and Katalon

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

I have tried two solutions for getting the INFO webdriver console logs for Chrome.

**The first method**,

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntries
import org.openqa.selenium.logging.LogEntry
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

WebUI.openBrowser(null)
WebUI.navigateToUrl(url)

WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
LogEntries logs = driver.manage().logs().get("browser")

for (LogEntry entry : logs){
         println(entry)
}
```

With the desired capabilities, as a list of arguments --enable-logging and --log-level=0

This method does not provide not provide any output.

**The second method**,

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences()
logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.INFO)
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs)

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps)
driver.get(url)
LogEntries logs = driver.manage().logs().get("browser")
```

This method works but forces me to launch a new instance of the webdriver and so requires me to set the desired capabilities using selenium.

---

I want to be able to have the desired capabilities inherited from Katalon. How can I get the first method to work?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Maybe there are no console messages from Chrome?

Comment: @MateMrše no error messages unfortunately. It completes successfully. I did check the size of logs and it appears to be empty but have no idea why. The url does have console logs.